# c# UWA public variable

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

```
String[] vals = s.Split(';');
String o = "X=" + vals[0] + "  Y=" + vals[1] + "  Z=" + vals[2];
var xValue = vals[0];
var yValue = vals[1];
var zValue = vals[2];
```

I want to use my variable "xValue, yValue, zValue" on another page. How do I make it public for me to use it.

This is the public class I created

```
public class CommonData
    {
        public static string o = string.Empty;
        public static void SetData(string s)
        {
            String[] vals = s.Split(';');
            o = "X=" + vals[0] + "  Y=" + vals[1] + "  Z=" + vals[2];
        }
    }
```

Comment: By not declaring it within a method, buit within the class itself. Please share the class and the method that contains the code and how and where you want to call it. We don´t know where you need the variables.

Comment: And where´s the problem on declaring `xValue` in your class as you did with `o` (`public static string xValue = null`) and *set* its value within your method? In fact you already did the same for `o`. I doun´t understand your problem.

Comment: I updated my answer with new example

Answer (score 1):

Making them `public` will solve your issue. You can access them further using object of that class.

I simulated your case in a console application. Declare those variable outside of method.

```
class Program
    {
        public static string xValue;
        public static string yValue;
        public static string zValue;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "fdf;fdfd;fdf";
            string[] vals = s.Split(';');
            string o = "X=" + vals[0] + "  Y=" + vals[1] + "  Z=" + vals[2];

            xValue = vals[0];
            yValue = vals[1];
            zValue = vals[2];

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```